# Xcode 5 xcodebuild unit test seems to return status successful when tests fail

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcodebuild, xctest

Hi I'm following examples from Test Driven iOS development and I've written a few unit tests with the new Xcode 5 and XCTest. My tests fail with the Xcode GUI client, but when I use xcodebuild the status code is 0.

`xcodebuild -target TemperatureConverterTests build`

and

`echo $?`

returns 0.

The tests are suppose to fail. Is the command to run the test cases correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) command has changed with xcode 5. Here is a script to run Unit tests :

Don't forget that schemes must be shared, **you've got to create your Tests Scheme, Xcode 5 didn't create it for you**

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme myApp-Tests -destination=build -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES clean build test
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you *don't want* (as you rarely need) a *separate* (and annoying) "scheme" for your testing "target"...  Use a variation on @Rémy Virin's answer...

`xcodebuild -scheme YourAppOrLib -target YourAppOrLibTests`

As pictured below.. this allows you to run the Unit tests for the target.... without cluttering the project with non-production schemes...  In this case `IndexedKeyMap` is my `YourAppOrLib`.

[image]